# IBDesignable rendering NSLayoutConstraint subclass

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I have develop a `DeviceLayout` Library [enter link description here](https://github.com/cruisediary/DeviceLayout)

[image]

this library provide `DeviceLayoutConstraint` to set AutoLayout constant per device size

```
import UIKit

import Device
class DeviceLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

    @IBInspectable var inch3_5: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { updateConstant(size: .screen3_5Inch, constant: inch3_5)}}
    @IBInspectable var inch4: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { updateConstant(size: .screen4Inch, constant: inch4)}}
    @IBInspectable var inch4_7: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { updateConstant(size: .screen4_7Inch, constant: inch4_7)}}
    @IBInspectable var inch5_5: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { updateConstant(size: .screen5_5Inch, constant: inch5_5)}}
    @IBInspectable var inch7_9: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { updateConstant(size: .screen7_9Inch, constant: inch7_9)}}
    @IBInspectable var inch9_7: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { updateConstant(size: .screen9_7Inch, constant: inch9_7)}}
    @IBInspectable var inch12_9: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { updateConstant(size: .screen12_9Inch, constant: inch12_9)}}

    fileprivate func updateConstant(size: Size, constant: CGFloat) {
        if size == deviceSize() {
            self.constant = constant
            layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    open func deviceSize() -> Size {
        return Device.deviceSize
    }

    open func layoutIfNeeded() {
        self.firstItem.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.secondItem?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

fileprivate extension Device {
    static let deviceSize = Device.size()
}
```

per device constant property applied in runtime simulator or device

My question is

Is it possible update rendering using IBInspectable or IBDesignable when select Device?

I want to check rendering in Storyboard or Xib file when device type changed

[image]

Comment: Completely unrelated, but I'm not sure I'd suggest calling `layoutIfNeeded` in `updateConstraint`. I'd probably call `setNeedsLayout`. If you happen to be updating a bunch of constants, you don't want to trigger too many redundant layout cycles.

Comment: Cruz did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: @Cruz: Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, constraints (whether your subclass or the standard constraints) are perfectly compatible with designable views. Clearly, it requires that your `@IBDesignable` view handles changes in size correctly, but we generally do that.

For example, if you have a designable view that adds a circular shaped `CAShapeLayer`, you'd add the `CAShapeLayer` once and only once in the appropriate `init` methods, but update that layer's `path` in the `layoutSubviews` method. For example, see [CircleView](https://github.com/robertmryan/CircularCollectionView/blob/master/CircularCollectionViewKit/CircleView.swift).

But if you handle size layout changes properly, you automatically handle constraints appropriately, too.

Comment: Hey Rob, Can you please explain how to use it with `NSLayoutConstraint` subclass?